# Magento syntax error when clicking on shipping method

Tags: json, magento, syntax, checkout

I have a Magento 1.8 webshop and everytime when i want to add a product and click on the desired shipping method i get a syntax error: invalid character.
I have looked in firebug and i get error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data.
I use onepagecheckout on the webshop.
Thanks!

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to the character encoding of the JSON. Oftentimes a few BOM bytes (byte-order mark) are prepended to JSON responses, depending on the encoding of the server code.